# How does a keyboard extension know that the document proxy has changed?

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension, ios-keyboard-extension

Keyboard extensions on iOS are subclasses of the `UIInputViewController` class and have the `textDocumentProxy` property to interact with the underlying document. The `textDocumentProxy` object exposes some important traits of the document, like the autocapitalization type. The question is, how does the keyboard extension know when the underlying document changes?

For example, when I tap to compose a new message in the Messages app, the “To” field uses different input traits than the message body input box. But since the keyboard doesn’t dissapear when switching focus from one field to the other, the text document proxy object changes on the fly. Can the keyboard extension notice such a change?

I’ve tried watching both the `textDocumentProxy` and `[[self textDocumentProxy] autocapitalizationType]` properties through KVO, but that doesn’t work. Checking the `autocapitalizationType` property using a timer reveals the change, but obviously I’d like to avoid a polling solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My `UIInputViewController` supports the `UITextInput` protocol, which has a `textDidChange` method. From `textDidChange`, I compare `self.textDocumentProxy` with my own `self.currentTextProxy` property. When the two differ, I update `self.currentTextProxy`, then refresh my GUI based upon the `self.textDocumentProxy`’s `UITextInputTraits`.

Comment: Thanks! I have completely missed the `UITextInputDelegate`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in iOS 10. it looks like the textDocumentProxy memory address never changes and they are just swapping out the input field behind the scenes.  Have you found a solution that still works?